# Exporting webform to MS Word

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, ms-word, export-to-word

I'm been looking through tutorials and other questions of how to export from asp.net to word but most I've found are dealing with a simple html table which isn't what I need or involve expensive extensions.

I have a webform which users complete and submit. Once submitted I want to give them to option to export it to Word (see screenshot).

I have tried right clicking and Save As as a test to see how it comes out and it's not neat at all (see screenshot).

When I print preview the page is also a mess due to the hamburger side bar (see screenshot) are these two issues related?

Any tips on getting the word doc to look similar to the webpage?

Sample of my code:

```
<!--Section 4 - Health & Safety-->
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseFour">Health & Safety</a>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <p>Have their been any changes to Health and Safety issues since the last assessment?</p>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <span class="checkableBox checkableBox-radio">
                    <asp:RadioButton class="validate[required]" ID="rbtnHealthYes" runat="server" value="Y" Text="Yes" GroupName="HealthAndSafetyChanges" />
                </span>
            </label>
            <label class="radio-inline">
                <span class="checkableBox checkableBox-radio">
                    <asp:RadioButton class="validate[required]" ID="rbtnHealthNo" runat="server" value="N" Text="No" GroupName="HealthAndSafetyChanges" />
                </span>
            </label>
            <br /><br />
            <p><i>If the answer to the above is yes, please give more details below and complete a new Health and Safety Assessment.</i></p>
            <asp:TextBox class="form-control input-sm auto-size m-b-10" ID="txtHealthDetails" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"
                placeholder="This could include things such as new renovations to the house or measures which have since broken.  (This text box will grow as you fill it)"></asp:TextBox>
            <hr class="whiter m-t-20" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <p>Additional Comments:</p>
            <asp:TextBox class="form-control input-sm auto-size m-b-10" ID="txtHealthComments" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"
                placeholder="(This text box will grow as you fill it)"></asp:TextBox>

        </div>
        <!--Body End -->
    </div>
    <!--Collapse 4 End -->
</div>
<!--Section 4 End -->
```

http://joshcoopster.tumblr.com/image/131738484325

http://joshcoopster.tumblr.com/image/131738526900

http://joshcoopster.tumblr.com/image/131738596840

Comment: Did you try to add the Word doc header to the html. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37019517/c-sharp-httpcontext-does-not-work-when-trying-to-save-html-to-word-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest would be to "transform" the information to a valid document type that Word can open and display. If standard HTML can give you the required quality, you can use that. If you need something more powerful you can use write WordOpenXML using the Open XML SDK.

One big question is, I suppose, whether you really need to show the form controls or whether just the information is good enough.